# Find integral from a known integral

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

The correct answer is $7$. I figured out that if you substitute the inner argument of the second function, the end points become the same but flipped. That means we can just negate the integral and get the same endpoints. This is where I am now stuck. How do I get to the result with that knowledge?

Comment: Yes, and if you substitute $7-8x$ you need to scale the integral by factor $-8$ what give you $(-8)\cdot (-7) = 56$ again. You just forgot to replace the "dx" by the substituted one.

Comment: @Gono Whoops! Dumb mistake on my end. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let $u = 7 - 8x$. Then, $u(0) = 7$ and $u(19) = -145$. Also, $dx = -\frac{du}{8}$. Then, we wish to calculate:

$$\int_{0}^{19}f(7-8x)\ dx = \int_{u(0)}^{u(19)}-f(u)\ \frac{du}{8} = -\frac{1}{8}\int_{7}^{-145}f(u)\ du = \frac{1}{8}\int_{-145}^{7}f(u)\ du =\frac{56}{8} = \boxed{7}$$

Comment: Yup! Thank you :) I forgot to substitute du in there as well.

Comment: Sorry, I had an error before. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting in the second argument  you get

$$-\frac{1}{8}\int_7^{-145}f(y)dy=\frac{1}{8}\int_{-145}^{7}f(y)dy=\frac{56}{8}=7$$